# How to redirect only localhost traffic in IIS 8

Tags: redirect, rewrite, localhost, iis-8

I have IIS 8 and I need redirect only localhost requests to one page to another page on the same IIS.

I tried it with URL Rewrite module and Conditions but maybe this is wrong way...

[image: Conditions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find an answer.
It has to be done on the root of the sites - like "Default Web Site".
And the web sites must have same application pool. If not, error page 403 will show up.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
       <rewrite>
           <rules>
               <rule name="RemoveDevices.aspx" enabled="true">
                   <match url="(.*/)Website/(Demo\.aspx)" />
                   <conditions>
                       <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="127\.0\.0\.1" negate="true" /> 
                       <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="10\.15\.1\.95" negate="true" /> <!--IP ADDRESS OF YOUR SERVER-->
                       <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="CZ-DEV095\.develop.local" negate="true" /> <!--HOST NAME OF YOUR SERVER-->
                       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}NEW_SITE/{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```